# Issue in versioning and metadata with recent Office Files

Tags: file-upload, versioning, metadata, file, file-metadata

I have a web service that shows a sort of CRUD of document (with metadata) for other application..

I have some document libraries in which users can upload (via WS) documents with metadatas.

For every kind of documents the upload of a new file works fine but when I upload new versions of particular file (DOCX, PPTX..) the metadata disappears in the new versions!

So.. how can I fix this problem? Is a well known bug or something new I have found?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem simply "rewriting down" the data inserted in the old item field.

Supposing my custom columns are:

- tt_file_id
- tt_content_id
- tt_Name

The code is:

```
SPListItem oldItem = list.GetItemById(OldItemID);
SPListItem newFile = (list.RootFolder.Files.Add(oldItem["Name"].ToString(), filebytes, true)).ListItemAllFields;

string Name = oldItem["Name"].ToString();
newFile["tt_file_id"] = oldItem["tt_file_id"];
newFile["Name"] = oldItem["Name"];
newFile["tt_content_id"] = oldItem["tt_content_id"];

newFile.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

check this link out on msdn forum as its the same question:

> For the ones (.docx / .xlsx) if you add metadata; you download the
>   document and upload it back again you will notice the field values
>   will be pre-populated and this is because of XML promotion and
>   demotion. To verify this:
>   Step 1: change the extension of your .docx
>   or .xlsx to .zip
>   Step 2: Open the zip file and look for a folder
>   customXml
>   Step 3: Open the folder and look for a file Item1.xml
>   When you open the file you will notice that the properties have the
>   same values as were assigned when you first uploaded the document.
>   This is the exact reason why you get the fields pre-populated once you
>   upload this document.    The above process is what is called as XML
>   promotion and demotion.  Hope this gives you an idea on what this is.
>
> ```
> Note: The above steps won't be true for .doc or .xls, for these types of documents you will notice that fields are always empty.
> ```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/1b115343-20e5-4962-af97-793194f07637